# in wordpress in appearence my theme has no background describing it

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In Wordpress, in the "Appearence" page, my custom theme has no background describing it. It just has a blank background like the image below. the theme is working properly and the site works just fine I but only have this problem.

appreciate any advice.
thanks

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5crfR.jpg)

Comment: your image name should be screenshot.png

Comment: Can you share me screenshot of your folder with screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a screenshot of your website, save it as a PNG file, name it `screenshot.png` and put it directly into your theme's main folder.

If it doesn't show immediately, you might want to clear all cache, reconnect to the server and/or change the theme back and forth after that.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom theme folder image name should be screenshot.png

and image size width 1200*900 for better solutions

Comment: I already put my screenshot.png in the theme folder and overwrite the existing but it still not showing